# Absolute value of real part in while loop expression

Tags: matlab, while-loop, absolute-value

I'm wondering when my while loop expression is satisfied. Err is a `[1x1551] complex double`. Is my loop stopping when one value satisfies the expression `(abs(real(err))>1e-4)`? or when all values in the array satisfies the expression. The function is converting towards a constant with increasing `p`

```
dt=0.01;
t=0:dt:T;
err=1;
p=-1;
dphi_sum=0;

while abs(real(err))>1e-4
    p=p+1
    dphi_sum2 = function(p);
    err = (dphi_sum+dphi_sum2)./(dphi_sum)-1;
    dphi_sum = dphi_sum+dphi_sum2;   
end
```

Comment: It seems for `all` the values in `err` if `dphi_sum2` is not a scalar. Also, why do you have a function named `function` there? It's out of the context though, but seemed like a bad practice.

Comment: Your loop will stop when any one of `abs(real(err)) <= 1e-4`. To continue looping, all the values must satisfy the condition.

Comment: Hint: why not try this at the command line? e.g. set `err = 1:5` and then try a basic while loop which starts with `while err>3`. What happens?